# Live filter/search of an array of objects doesn't work JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, javascript-objects

I can't seem to get this block of code to work. Any suggestions on how I can get it to work? It works if it's only an array, but when I make objects inside it doesn't show anything.

So could the problem be that the code dosent reach the objects?
So could the problem be that the code dosent reach the objects?
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dat0H.png)

```js
const playersArray = [{
    name: 'Darwin Núñez',
    number: 27,
    age: 23,
    position: 'Forward',
    image: 'nunez.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mohamed Salah',
    number: 11,
    age: 30,
    position: 'Midfielder',
    image: 'salah.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'Diogo Jota',
    number: 20,
    age: 25,
    position: 'Forward',
    image: 'jota.png'
  },
];

function updateResult(query) {
  let resultList = document.querySelector(".result");
  resultList.innerHTML = "";
  playersArray.map(function(player) {
    query.split(" ").map(function(word) {
      if (player.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        resultList.innerHTML += `<p class="list-group-item">${player}</p>`;
      }
    })
  })
}

updateResult("")
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 search-box">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input oninput="updateResult(this.value)" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="list-group result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Show your html as well, maybe thats the problem, and also what errors do you get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean `player.name.toLowerCase()` instead of `player.toLowerCase()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first we lowercase the `query`.
Then, we filter the array of players by checking each property.
Finally, we iterate the results and add them to the `p` element.
Have a nice day :)

```js
const playersArray = [{
    name: 'Darwin Núñez',
    number: 27,
    age: 23,
    position: 'Forward',
    image: 'nunez.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mohamed Salah',
    number: 11,
    age: 30,
    position: 'Midfielder',
    image: 'salah.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'Diogo Jota',
    number: 20,
    age: 25,
    position: 'Forward',
    image: 'jota.png'
  },
];

let resultList = document.querySelector(".result");

function updateResult(query) {
  if (query.length == 0) {
    resultList.innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  
  query = query.toLowerCase();

  let player = playersArray.filter(el => 
    el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.number.toString().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.age.toString().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.position.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.image.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1
  );
  resultList.innerHTML = "";
  player.forEach((data, index) => {
    resultList.innerHTML += `
      <div class="list-group-item" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 2px;">
        <div>Name: ${data.name}<div>
        <div>Id: ${data.number}<div>  
        <div>Age: ${data.age}<div>  
        <div>Position: ${data.position}<div> 
        <div>Image: ${data.image}<div> 
      </div>`;
  })
}

updateResult("")
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 search-box">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input oninput="updateResult(this.value)" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="list-group result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, that worked. The only thing thats wierd is that i see the whole object when i search :P

Comment: @maggyy yes. I just show the whole object because that is how you had it in your code. You are going to have to code that to print it pretty with HTML manually. Do you need me to do it for you or can you do it yourself?

Comment: would be helpful if you could show me how :)

Comment: There, I made it a little pretty. Don't forget to vote.

Comment: Yes i have tried to give u an upvote but i havent got enough points :/  BUT THANK U SO MUCH, ur an life saver! Ive made a new post if ur up for the task? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052327/filter-live-search-not-working-with-module-js