# Filter live/search not working with module JS

Tags: javascript, html

So, the code seems to work when I have the array of objects in the same JS file as the functions. As soon as I move the array to another file and then export it. The code won't run. Are there any smart people here that can find the error that makes it not run? If I remove defer type="module", from the script import it seems to run fine. But I need to make it an export module....

ERROR:
Uncaught ReferenceError: updateResult is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.oninput (page2.html:29)

```
// an object
export const playersArray = [
    {
        name: 'Darwin Núñez',
        number: 27,
        age: 23,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: 'nunez.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mohamed Salah',
        number: 11,
        age: 30,
        position: 'Midfielder',
        image: 'salah.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Diogo Jota',
        number: 20,
        age: 25,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: 'jota.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Luis Díaz',
        number: 23,
        age: 25,
        position: 'Forward',
        image: 'diaz.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jordan Henderson',
        number: 14,
        age: 32,
        position: 'Midfielder',
        image: 'henderson.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Virgil van Dijk',
        number: 4,
        age: 31,
        position: 'Defender',
        image: 'dijk.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Joël Matip',
        number: 32,
        age: 31,
        position: 'Defender',
        image: 'matip.png'
    },
    {
        name: 'Alisson Becker',
        number: 1,
        age: 30,
        position: 'Goalkeeper',
        image: 'alisson.png'
    },
    ];
// using JSON.stringify()
const jsonObj = JSON.stringify(playersArray);
// save to localStorage
localStorage.setItem("playersArray", jsonObj);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 search-box">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input oninput="updateResult(this.value)" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list-group result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script defer type="module" src="./scripts/page2.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
import { playersArray as _playersArray } from './array.js';
let playersArray = _playersArray;
playersArray.map(data => console.log(data +1))


let resultList = document.querySelector(".result");

function updateResult(query) {
  if (query.length == 0) {
    resultList.innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  
  query = query.toLowerCase();

  let player = playersArray.filter(el => 
    el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.number.toString().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.age.toString().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.position.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1
    || el.image.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1
  );
  resultList.innerHTML = "";
  player.forEach((data) => {
    resultList.innerHTML += `
      <div class="card list-group-item" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/${ data.image }" alt="Illustrasjon. Bildet av spiller.">
      <h4>${ data.name }</h4>
      <h5>Number: ${ data.number }</h5>
      <h5>Age: ${ data.age }</h5>
      <p>Position: ${ data.position }</p>
  </div>`;
  })
}

updateResult("")
```

Comment: Hello maggyy, There is no need to use the defer attribute when loading a module script; modules are deferred automatically. Btw, please share the error log.

Comment: okei, but removing it dosent resolve the problem. Ive added the error code, coudnt add the error as a image, thats wierd

Comment: please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630310/use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html for understanding why you are getting the error. In case, you dont have time to check it, add this  "window.updateResult = updateResult" at the end of that JS file where updateResult is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `module` script has it's own scope, while non-module scripts and HTML all share the same `window` scope

So, if you are trying to make

```html
<button onclick="click1()"> click me </button>
<script> function click1(){console.log('click1')} </script>
```

that will work, because `click1` is in the same scope, but

```html
<button onclick="click1()"> click me </button>
<-- well, modules can't be inlined, but for simplicity -->
<script type="module"> export function click1(){console.log('click1')} </script>
```

won't work, because `click1` is now not in `window` scope

Either
a) use non-module scripts. If you include multiple `<script>` tags, that would be mostly the same you want to achieve with imports
b) add `click1` to the `window` scope with `window.click1 = click1`
c) bind events prgrammatically with `el.addEventListener('click', click1)`
d) use async `import()` to import in non-module scripts